# Can you read an Excel xlsx row like a database row using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml

I just about lost my sanity yesterday with the disconnect between how easy this SHOULD be and the reality.  The workbook is using shared strings; I did find a way to get the cell value but it'd be nicer if I could just get what's being displayed in the cell instead of jumping through hoops.  More importantly, I need to get the values of columns A, B, and C for each row but if the value is blank, it treats it like the cell doesn't exist!  Can you fill in the pseudo code within the foreach Row statement?  Bonus if there's a way to get the value directly, but you can assume I have a method that will do all the string table lookup.

```
try
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("C:\\temp\\sitemap.xlsx", false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
        Sheets thesheetcollection = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
        StringBuilder excelResult = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Sheet thesheet in thesheetcollection)
        {
            excelResult.AppendLine("Excel Sheet Name : " + thesheet.Name);
            excelResult.AppendLine("----------------------------------------------- ");

            Worksheet theWorksheet = ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(thesheet.Id)).Worksheet;
            SheetData thesheetdata = (SheetData)theWorksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            foreach (Row thecurrentrow in thesheetdata)
            {
                // Help needed here
                var val1 = thecurrentrow[0].InnerText; // Col A
                var val2 = thecurrentrow[1].InnerText; // Col B
                var val3 = thecurrentrow[2].InnerText; // Col C
            }
            excelResult.Append("");
            Console.WriteLine(excelResult.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Comment: If "it treats it like the cell doesn't exist!" means "its value is null", check the value before assignment : `var val1 = thecurrentrow[0] == null ? string.Empty : thecurrentrow[0].InnerText;`

Comment: Unless you have really good reasons not to, you should use something like ClosedXML etc. OpenXML is very difficult and annoying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build all the cell addresses and then check if a cell with that address exists. Like this:

```
    private void ReadExcel()
    {
        for (int rowIdx = 1; rowIdx < 100; rowIdx++)
        {
            for (int colIdx = 1; colIdx < 30; colIdx++)
            {
                string cellAdress = $"{GetExcelColumnName(colIdx)}{rowIdx}";

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = theWorksheet.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CellReference == cellAdress);
                // if cell == null the cell has no value

            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber)
    {
        int dividend = columnNumber;
        string columnName = string.Empty;
        int modulo;

        while (dividend > 0)
        {
            modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
            columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
            dividend = (dividend - modulo) / 26;
        }

        return columnName;
    }
```

Comment: While you would have to match the cell reference, you would not implement it like this because enumerating the cells each time would be inefficient. So I would guess the author's point is more about matching the cell reference and checking for null than the implementation detail.